# Comparing random slopes from LME and individual linear models

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, random-effects-model

I want to know what is the difference between using linear mixed effect models or using a two sept approach where I first calculate linear stopes within each treatment and then calculate the average between them.

Below an example comparing random slopes from lm slopes. In the example above the outcome is very similar but when I compare results from these two approaches using my data I get very different results, with lm having much steeper slopes when compared to random effects from lme.

```
library(lme4)
data(sleepstudy) 

fml <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
beta <- coef(fml)$Subject
colnames(beta) <- c("intercept.lme", "slope.lme")
beta

reaction.trend <- data.frame (subject = unique (sleepstudy$Subject), slope.lm = NA)
  
  for (i in 1:nrow (reaction.trend)) {
    a <- sleepstudy [which (sleepstudy$Subject == reaction.trend$subject[i]),]
    reaction.trend [i,2] <- coef (lm (a$Reaction ~ a$Days))[2]
    }

beta$subject <- rownames(beta)
comp <- merge (reaction.trend, beta[,c('subject', 'slope.lme')])

plot (comp$slope.lm, comp$slope.lme)
abline (lm (comp$slope.lme ~ comp$slope.lm))
```

Comment: Is your data balanced (i.e., do you have the same number of observations for each subject)?

Comment: @Roland in my data I have number of observations varying between 3 and 25 with most of the subjects having 4 observations.

Comment: sleepstudy isn't a good comparison because all subjects have the same number of observations. There will be shrinkage back to the fixed effect value via the Empirical Bayes procedure, but the shrinkage will be the same for all. In your original data, where you have some people with more and some with less observations, shrinkage will vary depending on that.